# PowerShell - Changing output results from Many-to-Many to One-to-Many

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that I have put together from things I have found on the internet. The script gets a user from Microsoft Online and their license SkuId and returns the "friendly" name for the SkuId and outputs that to Excel. The Script works, but returns the DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, and License friendly name with each license on a different row. Here is an example:
[Example from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQgGp.png)

Here is the script that I am using:

```
function MSOLConnected 
    {
        Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | out-null
        $result = $?
        return $result
    }

$CSV = "C:\Temp\Office_365_User_Licensing.csv"

$Sku = @{
    "O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS"           = "Office 365 Business Essentials"
    "O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM"              = "Office 365 Business Premium"
    "DESKLESSPACK"                       = "Office 365 (Plan K1)"
    "DESKLESSWOFFPACK"                   = "Office 365 (Plan K2)"
    "LITEPACK"                           = "Office 365 (Plan P1)"
    "EXCHANGESTANDARD"                   = "Office 365 Exchange Online Only"
    "STANDARDPACK"                       = "Enterprise Plan E1"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACK"                   = "Office 365 (Plan E2)"
    "ENTERPRISEPACK"                     = "Enterprise Plan E3"
    "ENTERPRISEPACKLRG"                  = "Enterprise Plan E3"
    "ENTERPRISEWITHSCAL"                 = "Enterprise Plan E4"
    "STANDARDPACK_STUDENT"               = "Office 365 (Plan A1) for Students"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACKPACK_STUDENT"       = "Office 365 (Plan A2) for Students"
    "ENTERPRISEPACK_STUDENT"             = "Office 365 (Plan A3) for Students"
    "ENTERPRISEWITHSCAL_STUDENT"         = "Office 365 (Plan A4) for Students"
    "STANDARDPACK_FACULTY"               = "Office 365 (Plan A1) for Faculty"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACKPACK_FACULTY"       = "Office 365 (Plan A2) for Faculty"
    "ENTERPRISEPACK_FACULTY"             = "Office 365 (Plan A3) for Faculty"
    "ENTERPRISEWITHSCAL_FACULTY"         = "Office 365 (Plan A4) for Faculty"
    "ENTERPRISEPACK_B_PILOT"             = "Office 365 (Enterprise Preview)"
    "STANDARD_B_PILOT"                   = "Office 365 (Small Business Preview)"
    "VISIOCLIENT"                        = "Visio Pro Online"
    "POWER_BI_ADDON"                     = "Office 365 Power BI Addon"
    "POWER_BI_INDIVIDUAL_USE"            = "Power BI Individual User"
    "POWER_BI_STANDALONE"                = "Power BI Stand Alone"
    "POWER_BI_STANDARD"                  = "Power-BI Standard"
    "PROJECTESSENTIALS"                  = "Project Lite"
    "PROJECTCLIENT"                      = "Project Professional"
    "PROJECTONLINE_PLAN_1"               = "Project Online"
    "PROJECTONLINE_PLAN_2"               = "Project Online and PRO"
    "ProjectPremium"                     = "Project Online Premium"
    "ECAL_SERVICES"                      = "ECAL"
    "EMS"                                = "Enterprise Mobility Suite"
    "RIGHTSMANAGEMENT_ADHOC"             = "Windows Azure Rights Management"
    "MCOMEETADV"                         = "PSTN conferencing"
    "SHAREPOINTSTORAGE"                  = "SharePoint storage"
    "PLANNERSTANDALONE"                  = "Planner Standalone"
    "CRMIUR"                             = "CMRIUR"
    "BI_AZURE_P1"                        = "Power BI Reporting and Analytics"
    "INTUNE_A"                           = "Windows Intune Plan A"
    "PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT"              = "Office 365 Planner Preview"
    "ATP_ENTERPRISE"                     = "Exchange Online Advanced Threat Protection"
    "EQUIVIO_ANALYTICS"                  = "Office 365 Advanced eDiscovery"
    "AAD_BASIC"                          = "Azure Active Directory Basic"
    "RMS_S_ENTERPRISE"                   = "Azure Active Directory Rights Management"
    "AAD_PREMIUM"                        = "Azure Active Directory Premium"
    "MFA_PREMIUM"                        = "Azure Multi-Factor Authentication"
    "STANDARDPACK_GOV"                   = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan G1) for Government"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACK_GOV"               = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan G2) for Government"
    "ENTERPRISEPACK_GOV"                 = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan G3) for Government"
    "ENTERPRISEWITHSCAL_GOV"             = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan G4) for Government"
    "DESKLESSPACK_GOV"                   = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan K1) for Government"
    "ESKLESSWOFFPACK_GOV"                = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan K2) for Government"
    "EXCHANGESTANDARD_GOV"               = "Microsoft Office 365 Exchange Online (Plan 1) only for Government"
    "EXCHANGEENTERPRISE_GOV"             = "Microsoft Office 365 Exchange Online (Plan 2) only for Government"
    "SHAREPOINTDESKLESS_GOV"             = "SharePoint Online Kiosk"
    "EXCHANGE_S_DESKLESS_GOV"            = "Exchange Kiosk"
    "RMS_S_ENTERPRISE_GOV"               = "Windows Azure Active Directory Rights Management"
    "OFFICESUBSCRIPTION_GOV"             = "Office ProPlus"
    "MCOSTANDARD_GOV"                    = "Lync Plan 2G"
    "SHAREPOINTWAC_GOV"                  = "Office Online for Government"
    "SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE_GOV"           = "SharePoint Plan 2G"
    "EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE_GOV"          = "Exchange Plan 2G"
    "EXCHANGE_S_ARCHIVE_ADDON_GOV"       = "Exchange Online Archiving"
    "EXCHANGE_S_DESKLESS"                = "Exchange Online Kiosk"
    "SHAREPOINTDESKLESS"                 = "SharePoint Online Kiosk"
    "SHAREPOINTWAC"                      = "Office Online"
    "YAMMER_ENTERPRISE"                  = "Yammer Enterprise"
    "EXCHANGE_L_STANDARD"                = "Exchange Online (Plan 1)"
    "MCOLITE"                            = "Lync Online (Plan 1)"
    "SHAREPOINTLITE"                     = "SharePoint Online (Plan 1)"
    "OFFICE_PRO_PLUS_SUBSCRIPTION_SMBIZ" = "Office ProPlus"
    "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD_MIDMARKET"      = "Exchange Online (Plan 1)"
    "MCOSTANDARD_MIDMARKET"              = "Lync Online (Plan 1)"
    "SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE_MIDMARKET"     = "SharePoint Online (Plan 1)"
    "OFFICESUBSCRIPTION"                 = "Office ProPlus"
    "YAMMER_MIDSIZE"                     = "Yammer"
    "DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1"            = "Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement Plan Enterprise Edition"
    "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM_NOPSTNCONF"       = "Enterprise E5 (without Audio Conferencing)"
    "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM"                  = "Enterprise E5 (with Audio Conferencing)"
    "MCOSTANDARD"                        = "Skype for Business Online Standalone Plan 2"
    "PROJECT_MADEIRA_PREVIEW_IW_SKU"     = "Dynamics 365 for Financials for IWs"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_STUDENT"        = "Office 365 Education for Students"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_FACULTY"        = "Office 365 Education for Faculty"
    "EOP_ENTERPRISE_FACULTY"             = "Exchange Online Protection for Faculty"
    "EXCHANGESTANDARD_STUDENT"           = "Exchange Online (Plan 1) for Students"
    "OFFICESUBSCRIPTION_STUDENT"         = "Office ProPlus Student Benefit"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY"           = "Office 365 Education E1 for Faculty"
    "STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT"           = "Microsoft Office 365 (Plan A2) for Students"
    "DYN365_FINANCIALS_BUSINESS_SKU"     = "Dynamics 365 for Financials Business Edition"
    "DYN365_FINANCIALS_TEAM_MEMBERS_SKU" = "Dynamics 365 for Team Members Business Edition"
    "FLOW_FREE"                          = "Microsoft Flow Free"
    "POWER_BI_PRO"                       = "Power BI Pro"
    "O365_BUSINESS"                      = "Office 365 Business"
    "DYN365_ENTERPRISE_SALES"            = "Dynamics Office 365 Enterprise Sales"
    "RIGHTSMANAGEMENT"                   = "Rights Management"
    "PROJECTPROFESSIONAL"                = "Project Professional"
    "VISIOONLINE_PLAN1"                  = "Visio Online Plan 1"
    "EXCHANGEENTERPRISE"                 = "Exchange Online Plan 2"
    "DYN365_ENTERPRISE_P1_IW"            = "Dynamics 365 P1 Trial for Information Workers"
    "DYN365_ENTERPRISE_TEAM_MEMBERS"     = "Dynamics 365 For Team Members Enterprise Edition"
    "CRMSTANDARD"                        = "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online Professional"
    "EXCHANGEARCHIVE_ADDON"              = "Exchange Online Archiving For Exchange Online"
    "EXCHANGEDESKLESS"                   = "Exchange Online Kiosk"
    "SPZA_IW"                            = "App Connect"
    "WINDOWS_STORE"                      = "Windows Store for Business"
    "MCOEV"                              = "Microsoft Phone System"
    "VIDEO_INTEROP"                      = "Polycom Skype Meeting Video Interop for Skype for Business"
    "SPE_E5"                             = "Microsoft 365 E5"
    "SPE_E3"                             = "Microsoft 365 E3"
    "ATA"                                = "Advanced Threat Analytics"
    "MCOPSTN2"                           = "Domestic and International Calling Plan"
    "FLOW_P1"                            = "Microsoft Flow Plan 1"
    "FLOW_P2"                            = "Microsoft Flow Plan 2"
    "CRMSTORAGE"                         = "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online Additional Storage"
    "SMB_APPS"                           = "Microsoft Business Apps"
    "MICROSOFT_BUSINESS_CENTER"          = "Microsoft Business Center"
    "DYN365_TEAM_MEMBERS"                = "Dynamics 365 Team Members"
    "STREAM"                             = "Microsoft Stream Trial"
    "EMSPREMIUM"                         = "ENTERPRISE MOBILITY + SECURITY E5"
    "IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION"         = "Microsoft 365 E5 Security"
    "IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FOR_EMS_E5" = "Microsoft 365 E5 Security for EMS E5"
    "MCOPSTNC"                           = "Communications Credits"
    "MCOPSTN1"                           = "Microsoft 365 Domestic Calling Plan"
    "MCOCAP"                             = "Common Area Phone"
    "FORMS_PRO"                          = "Dynamics 365 Customer Voice Trial"
    "POWERAPPS_VIRAL"                    = "Power Apps Plan 2 Trial"
    "POWER_AUTOMATE_UNATTENDED_RPA"      = "Power Automate Unattended RPA add-on"
    "POWER_AUTOMATE_ATTENDED_RPA"        = "Power Automate Attended with RPA"
    
}

if (-not (MSOLConnected)) 
    {
        $Cred = Get-Credential
        Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
    }

$Users = Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE" -and $_.Department -like '*UWE*' } | Sort-Object DisplayName
Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    Write-Host "Working on $($User.DisplayName)..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    #Gets users license and splits it at the semicolon
    Write-Host "Getting all licenses for $($User.DisplayName)..." -ForegroundColor White
    $Licenses = ((Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $User.UserPrincipalName).Licenses).AccountSkuID
    If (($Licenses).Count -gt 1)
    {
        Foreach ($License in $Licenses)
        {
            Write-Host "Finding $License in the Hash Table..." -ForegroundColor White
            $LicenseItem = $License -split ":" | Select-Object -Last 1
            $TextLic = $Sku.Item("$LicenseItem")
            If (!($TextLic))
            {
                Write-Host "Error: The Hash Table has no match for $LicenseItem for $($User.DisplayName)!" -ForegroundColor Red
                $LicenseFallBackName = $License.AccountSkuId
                $NewObject02 = $null
                $NewObject02 = @()
                $NewObject01 = New-Object PSObject
                $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $User.DisplayName
                $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User Principal Name" -Value $User.UserPrincipalName
                $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "License" -Value "$LicenseFallBackName"
                $NewObject02 += $NewObject01
                $NewObject02 | Export-CSV $CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
            }
            Else
            {
                
                $NewObject02 = $null
                $NewObject02 = @()
                $NewObject01 = New-Object PSObject
                $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $User.DisplayName
                $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User Principal Name" -Value $User.UserPrincipalName
                $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "License" -Value "$TextLic"
                $NewObject02 += $NewObject01
                $NewObject02 | Export-CSV $CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Finding $Licenses in the Hash Table..." -ForegroundColor White
        $LicenseItem = ((Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $User.UserPrincipalName).Licenses).AccountSkuID -split ":" | Select-Object -Last 1
        $TextLic = $Sku.Item("$LicenseItem")
        If (!($TextLic))
        {
            Write-Host "Error: The Hash Table has no match for $LicenseItem for $($User.DisplayName)!" -ForegroundColor Red
            $LicenseFallBackName = $License.AccountSkuId
            $NewObject02 = $null
            $NewObject02 = @()
            $NewObject01 = New-Object PSObject
            $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $User.DisplayName
            $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User Principal Name" -Value $User.UserPrincipalName
            $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "License" -Value "$LicenseFallBackName"
            $NewObject02 += $NewObject01
            $NewObject02 | Export-CSV $CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
        Else
        {
            $NewObject02 = $null
            $NewObject02 = @()
            $NewObject01 = New-Object PSObject
            $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $User.DisplayName
            $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User Principal Name" -Value $User.UserPrincipalName
            $NewObject01 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "License" -Value "$TextLic"
            $NewObject02 += $NewObject01
            $NewObject02 | Export-CSV $CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to display the results on only one row. So only one DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, and then a different column for each License. Something that would look like this:
[Preferred Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFrkT.png)  I have tried to do a Pivot in Excel but the results are still vertical not horizontal.

I don't know if I could use a `Group-Object` and group on the name or what. I don't have a lot of experience with PowerShell so I am unsure how to do this or if it is possible.

Comment: An issue I foresee is with `Export-Csv`. In order to export to a csv there needs to be unique names for the columns, whereas you're trying to have multiple `license` headers.